# Matlab's triu function to vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A,

```
A = [1 2 0; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;]

1   2   0
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

Matlab has a `triu` function which does the following,

```
triu(A)

1   2   0
0   5   6
0   0   9
```

I need a function like that which gives me a vector like that:

triu_vector(A) --> [1 2 0 5 6 9]

PS: Trianguler matrix of `A` may contain `0`'s. That's why I cannot use Matlab's `nonzeros` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
A = [1 2 0; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;];

I = true(size(A));
At = A';
At(tril(I))'
```

then

```
ans =

   1   2   0   5   6   9
```

Comment: I will flag this as the answer since it was the first working answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If order does not matter:

```
A(triu(true(size(A)))).'
```

if order *does* matter:

```
A = A.';
A(tril(true(size(A)))).'
```